# How to work email subscribe in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

There are many website those are using new WordPress theme as email subscribe option,  like the below image

http://postimg.org/image/6kh8b1wfb/

and I wish I will add this subscribe option in my theme.I have styling idea but I haven't  any WordPress functional idea how to working the subscribe option. I searched google but didn't got any information about it.

So I need informational article on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wordpress plugins to achieve this functionality.You can install  following plugins from your wordpress admin. The installation guide is given on the plugin page.

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/newsletter/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-newsletter/
```

Comment: I don't need plugin. I want to know about function and how it's work .

Comment: basically, its html to php. it takes the input email address, checks to see if it already exists, if not, it'll add the email to the db and send confirmation email to the user that they signed up and maybe another confirmation email to the web master.